# finding distinct pairs in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I was trying to learn non-equi joins when I encountered this problem. I have a table pops:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| country    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| continent  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| population | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I was trying to find countries with their population in the vicinity of say, 100.

```sql
   select distinct 
       p1.country, 
       p2.country, 
       p1.population, 
       p2.population 
   from pops p1 
       inner join pops p2 
           on p1.population between p2.population - 100 and p2.population + 100 
           and p1.country <> p2.country  
   where p2.country <> p1.country
```

output I got was:

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| country    | country    | population | population |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| pakistan   | india      |      99988 |      99999 |
| china      | india      |      99990 |      99999 |
| bangladesh | japan      |        999 |        999 |
| india      | pakistan   |      99999 |      99988 |
| china      | pakistan   |      99990 |      99988 |
| japan      | bangladesh |        999 |        999 |
| india      | china      |      99999 |      99990 |
| pakistan   | china      |      99988 |      99990 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

as we can see, I am getting pairs of (india, pakistan) as well as (pakistan, india), which is data-wise the same thing. Is it possible to eliminate one of the records from the pair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could decide to always have the lexographically first (or last, for argument's sake) country on the p1 side - use `<` (or `>`) instead of `<>`.
Also, note that your `where` clause is redundant, since you already have this condition in the `on` clause of the `join`:

```sql
select     p1.country, 
           p2.country, 
           p1.population, 
           p2.population 
from       pops p1 
inner join pops p2 
           on p1.population between p2.population - 100 and p2.population + 100 and
               p1.country < p2.country  
-- Here ------------------^
```

Comment: can you explain p1.country < p2.country part

Comment: Using `<` instead of `<>` guarantees you'll always get the "first" country on the left. That way you only get (india, pakistan) instead of (india, pakistan) and (pakistan, india).

Answer (score 3):

just change the join condition of p1.country <> p2.country to p1.country < p2.country